# Fix field of a certain galois group action

Tags: proof-verification, galois-theory, group-actions, galois-representations

Let $E= \mathbb{F}_p(\!(u)\!)$, $E^s$ a separable closure of $E$ and write $G_E= \mathrm{Gal}(E^s/E)$ for the absolute Galois group of $E$. Take a lift of the $u$-adic valuation on $E$ to $E^s$ and write $\nu \colon E^s \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ for the resulting valuation. Let $\hat{E^s}$ be a completion of $E^s$ with regard to this valuation. 
We obtain a $G_E$ action on $\hat{E^s}$ by continuity. Is it true that $(\hat{E^s})^{G_E}=E$?

I would argue that yes, namely let $x \in \hat{E^s}$, then $x= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x_i$ with $x_i \in E^s$ and $\nu(x_i) < \nu(x_{i+1})$. Assume that that $x=g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} g(x_i)$ for all $g \in G_E$. But $\nu(g(x_i))= \nu(x_i)$ as $g(u)=u$. Therefore $g(x_i)=x_i$ for all $i$ and we see $x_i \in E$ and thus $x \in E$.

Is my reasoning correct? My intuition would tell me that as $\hat{E^s}$ is 'a lot bigger' than $E^s$, also its fixed field under the $G_E$ action should be bigger, which makes me doubt my own argument.

Comment: Your conjecture must be true, but I’m not remembering the right argument.But I have two comments: (1) your statement $v(x_i)<v(x_{i+1})$ is not strong enough, since this doesn’t imply that $v(x_i)\uparrow\infty$. And (2), If $v(g(x_i))=v(x_i)$, you can’t conclude that $g(x_i)=x_i$.

Comment: Hello Lubin. Of course I don't say "$x \in E^s$ if and only if $x$ is of this form, but I want to say "if $x \in E^s$, then in particular...

Comment: I recognize that. I was thinking, though, about how I would try to prove the statement, and a mere increase of the valuations wouldn’t be sufficient to that purpose.

Comment: I see. Of course your second point is valid and the approach presented above will not work... however, I am still very much interested in the result.

Comment: I am too. I seem to recall that a suitable form of Krasner’s Lemma is involved — I’ll try to think about it later.

Comment: I knew the ingredients to nfdc23’s comment on MO, but had not put them together. Since the completion of the separable closure contains (purely) inseparable elements, the conjecture can not be correct.